# How to query row with max value in a column in a referencing table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group

There are popular case, where is needed to select a row with max value (or min or whatever else aggregate function result) from a table. My case is more complex - it adds `JOIN` into the picture.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE spacecraft (
  id   serial PRIMARY KEY, 
  name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE launch (
  id            serial PRIMARY KEY,
  spacecraft_id int REFERENCES spacecraft(id) NOT NULL,
  started       timestamptz NOT NULL,
  success       bool NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO spacecraft (id, name) VALUES 
    (1, 'Bebop'), 
    (2, 'Serenity'), 
    (3, 'Death Start');

INSERT INTO launch (spacecraft_id, started, success) VALUES 
    (1, 'January 8 04:05:06 2999 UTC', true), 
    (2, 'December 1 01:00:00 3432 UTC', true), 
    (3, 'February 15 00:00:00 4521 UTC', false), 
    (3, 'July 10 12:05:00 4525 UTC', true);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a1921

How to select last launch result (launch.success) for each spacecraft?

### UPDATE #1

That's my current solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.*, last_launch, L2.success FROM spacecraft AS S
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT *, MAX(started) OVER (PARTITION BY spacecraft_id) AS last_launch FROM launch) AS L1
ON L1.spacecraft_id=S.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN launch AS L2
ON L2.started=L1.last_launch;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/45618/38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want all columns from `spacecraft` in the result, plus the latest `launch` and the `success` of the same row.

Faster for few launches per spacecraft:

```
SELECT s.*, l.last_launch, l.success
FROM   spacecraft s
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (spacecraft_id)
          spacecraft_id, started AS last_launch, success
   FROM   launch
   ORDER  BY spacecraft_id, started DESC
   ) l ON l.spacecraft_id = s.id;
```

Faster for many launches per spacecraft:

```
SELECT s.*, l.last_launch, l.success
FROM   spacecraft s
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT started AS last_launch, success
   FROM   launch
   WHERE  spacecraft_id = s.id
   ORDER  BY started DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) l ON true;
```

`LATERAL` requires Postgres 9.3+.
`LEFT JOIN` to include spacecrafts without any launches. Else use `JOIN`.

The essential ingredient to make either of these queries ***fast*** is a multicolumn index on `(spacecraft_id, started)`. For this particular query it would be beneficial to `success` to the index to allow index-only scans:

```
CREATE INDEX launch_foo_idx ON launch (spacecraft_id, started DESC, success);
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f0e81/1)

Detailed explanation:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only max of success, so you have add a condition to filter only success. and using [Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html) as you did:

```
select spacecraft.* , max(started) over (partition by spacecraft.id)  
from spacecraft 
    left outer join 
    launch 
    on spacecraft.id = spacecraft_id
where success
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/45618/48)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, l.last_started
FROM spacecraft AS s
INNER JOIN (SELECT spacecraft_id, MAX(started) AS last_started FROM launch WHERE success GROUP BY spacecraft_id) AS l
ON s.id = l.spacecraft_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/45618/50